# adding a shortcode into a custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, shortcode, uploads

I want to add the upload file plugin shortcode to a custom post type for a client build (if there's a better way to do this, please tell me). Basically I've got this -

```
echo '<p>Description:</p>';
echo '<input type="text" name="_Description" value="' . $Description . '" class="widefat" />';
echo '<p>Requirement:</p>';
echo '<input type="text" name="_Requirement" value="' . $Requirement . '" class="widefat" />';
echo '<p>Solution:</p>';
echo '<input type="text" name="_Solution" value="' . $Solution . '" class="widefat" />';
echo '<?php do_shortcode("[inline_upload]"); ?>';
```

this doesn't throw any errors on the page but the outputted is

```
<!--?php do_shortcode("[inline_upload]"); ?-->
```

Is it possible to add a shortcode to a custom post type? Is there an easier, cleaner way to do this?

Thanks in advance

edit:

The code is in a custom post type file that I'm calling via the functions.php to be part of the menu system. Clicking add new to it creates all the forms but outputs the

I guess I'm doing it wrong?

Comment: Where is that code? Are you typing that PHP into the backend editor?

Comment: "*The code is in a custom post type file that I'm calling via the functions.php to be part of the menu system.*" - this isn't making sense to me. Where exactly is this code being called (and output)? In a template file? In a callback to some hook? And how is it added to the menu system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand this correctly it looks like

`echo '<?php do_shortcode("[inline_upload]"); ?>';`

should be `echo do_shortcode("[inline_upload]");`

So that it actually runs the short code instead of echoing the code.